# Adding large matrices ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, concurrency, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a program which adds two integer matrices together and I am running into an **ArayIndexOutOfBounds** exception when trying to process larger matrices. Any advice on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[ArrayOutOfBoundsException on cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpfHe.png)

Here is the class in which the error is occuring:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreadMaker
{
    public static int count=0;
    
    public static void addmatrix(int[][] mat_A,int[][] mat_B,int[][] submatrix1,int[][] submatrix2,int N,int M)throws Exception
    {
        ThreadOperation m1;
        ThreadOperation.initialize(N,M);
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        int c=0,d;
        while(c<N)
        {
            d=0;
            while(d<M)
            {
                int i=0,j=0,k,l;
                for(k=0,i=c; i < c + N/2; i++, k++)
                {
                    for(l=0,j=d; j < d + M/2; j++, l++)
                    {
                        submatrix1[k][l]=mat_A[i][j];
                        submatrix2[k][l]=mat_B[i][j];
                    }
                }
                m1=new ThreadOperation(mat_A,mat_B,submatrix1,submatrix2,N,M,c,d);
                Thread thread =new Thread(m1);
                thread.start();
                threads.add(thread);
                thread.join();
                d=d+M/2;
            }
            c=c+N/2;
        }
    }
    
    public static void devidematrix(int[][] mat_A,int[][] submatrix,int N,int M)
    {
        int c=0,d;
        while(c<N)
        {
            d=0;
            while(d<M)
            {
                int i=0,j=0,k,l;
                for( k=0,i=c;i<c+N/2;i++,k++)
                {
                    for( l=0,j=d;j<d+M/2;j++,l++)
                    {
                        submatrix[k][l]=mat_A[i][j];
                    }
                }
                d=d+M/2;
            }
            c=c+N/2;
        }
    } 
    public synchronized static void printmatrix(int[][] matrix,int row,int col)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Here is the martix from  the **matrix2.txt** file:
4 7
2 3 1 2 5 1 2
3 1 2 2 2 4 4
1 2 3 2 7 2 1
3 6 1 5 1 3 5
6 5 4 1 4 3 1
3 3 2 2 1 1 2
7 5 4 3 2 5 3
2 1 8 4 8 4 4

If any more information is need please let me know.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to add smaller matricies, such as 
4 6
2 3 1 2 5 1
3 1 2 2 2 4
1 2 3 2 7 2
3 6 1 5 1 3
6 5 4 1 4 3
3 3 2 2 1 1
7 5 4 3 2 5
2 1 8 4 8 4
But I am struggling to have the program read larger matrices

Comment: Can you add the parts where you declare the sizes of your matrices?